# Why do I lose my javascript from the browser cache after a full page postback?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have an external javascript file which I include to my page on the code behind (as seen below).

My problem is, when I my page makes a postback (not partial one), I check the loaded scripts by using FireBug, and I cannot see the javascript file in the list after the post back. I asusmed once it is included to page on the first load, browser will be caching it so that I do not need to re-include it.

What am I doing wrong?

The way I include the script is here:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

    if (this.Page.IsPostBack==false)
    {
        if (this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("ctlPalletDetail")==false)
        {
            string guidParamToHackBrowserCaching = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("ctlPalletDetail", ResolveUrl(String.Format("~/clientScripts/ctlLtlRequestDetail.js?par={0}",guidParamToHackBrowserCaching)));
        }
    }

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The browser **will** be caching it to save it from downloading again on postback. 
But you still need to register to script on the page to tell the browser to actually USE the cached script into the page.

Or in other words: registering the script on the server will render a <script> tag on the served page that will tell the browser to actually use that script file.

Wether the script is cached locally or not on the client doesn't have any bearing.If the script is not already cached then the browser will download it. If it is cached, it will not use it unless you tell it to (via the <script> tag)

Comment: So does this mean if I re-include a script with an Id which belongs to a js file and which was loaded by the browser before, it will be registered but not loaded once again?

Comment: When it will be registered, a script tag will be rendered in the HTML. Then, depending on the browser's cache settings, the client browser will not download the file again.